# Are there EU Regulations/Laws or French Laws regarding hotel services/amenities?

Tags: legal, france, hotels, regulations, eu

As the title says are there any laws or regulations that state what services/amenities must be provided inclusive of stay in hotel/motel in France?

Booked a holiday to the French Alps and the self-catered hotel were staying in, are now telling us we have to pay an extra 10-15€ for bed linen.

Is this allowed?

Comment: Just tell them that you don't need bed linen and use your sleeping bag ;)

Comment: Am hoping not to take a sleeping bag as it takes up a lot of room in my bag! Hoping I can tell the hotel/organisers they have to give me ben linen!

Comment: @Aran: Have you read the fine print on the booking?

Comment: Some places ban sleeping bags because they're the major vector for [bed bugs](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3461/what-are-the-signs-of-a-bed-bug-infestation) to be introduced.

Comment: You can take your own bed linen. If you are tight for space take a *sheet sleeping bag*.

Comment: “Hotels” are not usually “self-catered” in France. Maybe something got lost in translation and what you booked does not really sound like a hotel. It is frequent to be charged separately for bed linen, towels and weekly cleaning in “gîte” and other type of self-catered holiday rentals but it would of course usually not be advertised as “hotel” and clearly specified.

Answer (score 7):

If what you name a "self-catered hotel" is a "[gîte](http://www.gites-de-france.com/)", paying an extra for bed linen is usual. What is not is that the owner didn't mention it on the renting contract.

Comment: Wasn't mentioned until we got our e-tickets. :-/

Comment: I think that's the most important sentence: If it was not mentioned before signing the contract, it is definitively not normal.

Comment: @Aran, Roflcoptr: It may be legitimate not to mention this explicitly. That depends entirely on what type of room was advertised. For example, if this was an official *gîte*, then only [categories 2 and above](http://www.gites-de-france.com/classement-gite.html) include linen, category 1 might not. A *gîte* in the Alps might have a large clientèle that drives there and can take linen from home.